# Why is there a proxy reading in this sentence from Reuland (2011)?

Tags: syntax, english, binding-theory

For English, himself can function as proxy reading, for instance,

One of the well-known properties of reflexive pronouns is their ability to
have "proxy readings." This is illustrated in (1) (Jackendoff 1992):

(1) (Upon a visit in a wax museum:) All of a sudden Ringo started
undressing **himself**.

Himself in (1) can be interpreted as the "real" Ringo, but also as a statue
of the Ringo denoted by the subject.

But for these two sentences from Reuland (2011：88)

（2）*Max boasted that the queen invited [Lucie and **himself**] for a drink.*

（3）**Max boasted that the queen invited himself for a drink.*

Reuland (2011:89): the syntactic internal argument of 'invite' is 'Lucie and himself'. Thus, 'himself' is not a syntactic argument of 'invite'; it gets both Case and theta-role only indirectly. Therefore, himself does not reflexive-mark the syntactic predicate of invite, **which entails that it need not be reflexive**.

So in this case, (2) himself is not a reflexive according to Reuland?

Comment: What's your guess and why? There are not that many candidates in the example sentence.  Knowing where your confusion lies would help the community help you.

Comment: @jogloran Thanks.  I guess it is hard for me to understand what proxy reading is even though I read Reuland's paper.  Is Max the antecedent of "himself"?

Comment: @Xia.Yili Who else could it be? It can’t be Lucie, or it would say “Lucie and Lucie”, which makes no sense; and the queen is a she, based on her title, so it can’t be her either. Who else is left?

Comment: Also, it's good scholarship to actually state which work you're talking about. While I can guess what work Reuland (2011) refers to, you should consider supplying the reference so everyone can find the work you're drawing from.

Comment: @jogloran Thanks for reminding. I am working on binding theory in Chinese.  I read that the pronouns and reflexives have proxy reading so I am curious about why.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Rueland said that "himself" doesn't refer to anyone in the sentence. It doesn't function as reflexive.

Comment: @Xia.Yili If Reuland said that, then they’re wrong. ‘Himself’ refers to Max. It doesn’t refer to anyone in the _clause_ (“that the queen invited Lucie and himself”), but it does refer to someone in the _sentence_. (Although, if we take ‘queen’ to refer to a drag queen who is actually male-identifying, ‘himself’ _could_ be reflexive and refer to the queen. But that’s a bit of a stretch. Even male-identifying drag queens tend to use female pronouns about their drag personas.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think his judgement in Reuland(2011) might be not accurate.  Thanks for your replying.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet well, Reuland is *not* wrong - it's just his views are misrepresented here.

Comment: @AlexB. I suspected that was the case. A claim that _himself_ here does not refer to anyone in the sentence is so blatantly wrong that it would be very surprising to find it in a peer-reviewed, published work.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet just to get an idea of what Reuland actually meant, see https://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780199935345.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780199935345-e-9 (scroll down to **5.2.3. Protecting and Enforcing**)

Comment: @AlexB. Sorry I misunderstood here.  Himself did refer to Max.